# Best chat server selection for workgroup chat similar to live chat?

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I am finding a solution to implement a customized **workgroup chat** application similar to [live chat](http://www.boldchat.com). I came across two different protocols to support this [XMPP](http://xmpp.org) & [COMETD](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/cometd-facebook-similar-chat-for-your.html).

After some more research I found that XMPP is the best choice. When it comes to chat server part I am **confused between selecting [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) or [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/)**. I found openfire [fastpath](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/fastpath/readme.html) plugin to support my workgroup queue chat requirement. But similar type of plugin I could not find in ejabberd. Are there any existing plugin in ejabberd for this?

**As I am new to this area can someone suggest me to select the right technologies suitable for me**. Below are my requirements.

1. Fully customized chat client for users. Before each person initiates the chat need to take few input parameters. (Found this in sample [fastpath webchat](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/webchat/readme.html) plugin supporting my requirements)
2. Most of the users will be using this in Ipad. So in mobile network and mobile devices it should work well.
3. Need to store all the conversations in database to get the statistics later.
4. Chat server should support ldap authentication.
5. Work group support with Queue. Each agent I should be able to assign a work groups.

   Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use node.js for getting best chat server.

Comment: @Manish How about the support for workgroup chat? Are there any existing plugin like openfire fastpath to do this or do I need to write from scratch?

Comment: @DonX Any progress? Have you find any plugin for work-group implementation?

Comment: @UdaySawant I could not find any other option. So I went with openfire   chat server with fastpath plugin for work-group implementation. Fastpath plugin serves the all the features required for work-group implementation. And everything can be customized.